# How to select records only of last 1 minute in MYSQL DB with Python

Tags: python, mysql, select

I have a MYSQL database table like,

```
received_time    -    message
--------------------------------
 08:20:30        -   I'm happy with your service 
 08:20:33        -   I'm your customer
 08:21:40        -   We hate about your customer service
```

I want to select messages that received within last one minute. I used following query.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Message FROM all_message WHERE received_time >= NOW() -INTERVAL 1 MINUTE")
results = [res[0] for res in cursor.fetchall()]
print results
```

But it returns null value. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `received_time` datatype is `DATETIME` or `TIME` ?

Comment: It is TIME datatype.

Comment: Works fine with the query part, check the [demo](http://rextester.com/OFRUM10029)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Message FROM all_message WHERE received_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

You have to execute this query before 1 minutes after insertion of record.

Try above code.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Your script make some error which is "_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)' at line 1")
"

Comment: But now it provide null result.How it is possible to return null?

Comment: @ChathurikaJayawardana as there is no result in your table at date `'2017-06-15 15:38:47'`. If you want to check that query is working proper or not just make one entry into your table and run this query within minute.You will get output.

Comment: can I select records that received per 1 minute, instead of last minute in current time ?

Comment: @ChathurikaJayawardana Yes obviously..!!

Comment: How can I do it? please help me.